# Applescript that efficiently listens for changes to the clipboard?

Tags: applescript, python, copy-paste

I'd like to do something whenever clipboard content changes.  I have a solution working now where I get the clipboard value and store it, then I start an infinite loop where I look up the clipboard again, see if it's changed, then sleep for 0.5s and do it all over again.

This definitely works, but I want to do this better! Would prefer if I can listen for a notification that just tells me when the clipboard changes. There's a `UIPasteboardChanged` event [in UIKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotification.name/1622104-uipasteboardchanged) that lets you do this, but would prefer not needing to write this in Swift code to accomplish my goal. :-)

Any ideas on how to do this in Applescript/Automator/Python?  Thanks!

Comment: Is Swift/Objective C/Cocca in Apple Script cheating?

Comment: that'd still be helpful to me if you had some sample code! I suspect that'd still be simpler than making a full dedicated Swift app, though at this point it's looking like I might have to go that route.

Comment: Not experienced in those languages, but am skilled in Apple Script an I know there’s a way to do use those languages. I left the question for someone else to pickup.

Comment: Unfortunately, no answer as been found. [Heres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29516503/get-notified-on-clipboard-change-in-swift?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) how to do it in swift.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up solving this by using Objective C bindings for Python. So not really an AppleScript answer.  It's still polling based, but it's about 1000x more CPU efficient than calling out to `pbpaste` from the shell.

After installing the [AppKit](https://pypi.org/project/AppKit/) python bindings, I can fetch the current pasteboard like this:

```
from AppKit import NSPasteboard, NSStringPboardType
NSPasteboard.generalPasteboard().stringForType_(NSStringPboardType)
```

I run this in a tight loop, polling every second, and its CPU usage is quite negligible.